# Stacked horizontal bar chart along total count with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am unable to find the solution to add the total count for Stacked horizontal bar chart !

codepen link: [code link](https://codepen.io/bvsbharat/pen/rGOmGj)
[image]`enter code here`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following code to draw/add total count in your stacked horizontal bar chart :

```
this.data.datasets[0].data.forEach(function(data, index) {
   var total = data + this.data.datasets[1].data[index];
   var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(1);
   var posX = meta.data[index]._model.x;
   var posY = meta.data[index]._model.y;
   ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
   ctx.fillText(total, posX + 4, posY + 4);
}, this);
```

<sup>add this inside chart­*'s* animation onComplete function.</sup>

[**ʟɪᴠᴇ ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**](https://codepen.io/gaand/pen/boVWPV)

Comment: Awesome Thank you!

Comment: Could you help me in removing the lines in the graph which are in the background!

Comment: but it removing the first line also which is parallel to label, and in the bottom of the y-axis label have a small line if u see the mockup

Comment: We need to remove only the body part line not outside part

Comment: ok, let me check.. could you perhaps post a different question regarding this issue.. *(as it seems not relevant to your original question)* ?

Comment: new Question posted :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261082/in-stacked-horizontal-bar-chart-how-to-remove-the-horizontal-line-in-chart-js

Comment: Im getting a 'ctx is undefined' error.