# In Stacked horizontal bar chart how to remove the vertical line in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am unable to find the solution to remove the line in graph area for Stacked horizontal bar chart! , below mocke up show the details where i need the x and y axis line need to be shown but currently the when i set the gridLabel:{display:none} every vertical lines are removed

```js
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
          fontSize: 11
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false
        },
      gridLines: {
          display: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
          fontSize: 11
        },
        stacked: true
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          color: "#fff",
          zeroLineColor: "#fff",
          zeroLineWidth: 0
        },
        ticks: {
          fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
          fontSize: 11
        },
        stacked: true
      }
    ]
  },
```

codepen link: [code link](https://codepen.io/bvsbharat/pen/NaGgWN)
[image]

Comment: Which line are you talking about? The X-axis (i.e. the one labeled 200, 400, 600, 800)? Are you wanting just the line removed? The line and labels? The tick marks?

Comment: sorry i went for some other work

Comment: please sorry for non response  I need the x-axis line to be der but inside graph area the line i removed

Comment: @YvetteColomb sorry for the confusion! i am done with edit part

Comment: @Makyen sorry for the confusion! i am done with edit part, please let me know if my question is not clear!

Comment: *Exactly* which line you desire to remove is not clear. Are you wanting to remove the x-axis? Just the x-axis horizontal line? The line and tick marks? The line, tick marks, and labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following properties for x-axis grid-lines :

```
drawOnChartArea: false,
color: "black",
zeroLineColor: "black"
```

also, change the color for y-axis grid-lines :

```
color: "black"
```

[**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**](https://codepen.io/gaand/pen/EwVXPR)

```js
var barOptions_stacked = {
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false
  },
  hover: {
    animationDuration: 0
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
          fontSize: 11
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          color: "black",
          zeroLineColor: "black"
        },
        stacked: true
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          color: "black",
          zeroLineColor: "#fff",
          zeroLineWidth: 0
        },
        ticks: {
          fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
          fontSize: 11
        },
        stacked: true
      }
    ]
  },
  legend: {
    display: false
  },

  animation: {
    onComplete: function() {
      var chartInstance = this.chart;
      var ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
      ctx.textAlign = "left";
      ctx.font = "9px Open Sans";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

      Chart.helpers.each(
        this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
          var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
          Chart.helpers.each(
            meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
              data = dataset.data[index];
              if (i == 0) {
                ctx.fillText(data, 50, bar._model.y + 4);
              } else {
                ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x - 25, bar._model.y + 4);
              }
            }),
            this
          );
        }),
        this
      );
    }
  },
  pointLabelFontFamily: "Quadon Extra Bold",
  scaleFontFamily: "Quadon Extra Bold"
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart1");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "horizontalBar",
  data: {
    labels: ["82", " 81 ", "2", " 42", "4"],

    datasets: [
      {
        data: [727, 589, 537, 543, 20],
        backgroundColor: "#5f8a58",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(50,90,100,1)"
      },
      {
        data: [238, 553, 746, 884, 122],
        backgroundColor: "#3f7faa",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(140,85,100,1)"
      },
      {
        data: [100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(140,85,100,1)"
      }
    ]
  },

  options: barOptions_stacked
});
```

```css
.graph_container {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.js"></script>
<div class="graph_container">
  <canvas id="Chart1"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Neither the snippet, nor the code on codepen, appear to get rid of the x-axis.

Comment: @Makyen what OP actually meant is to remove the vertical gridlines from graph/chart area *(as seen on the given image)*.. so I believe I gave the right solution..

Comment: I'm really not sure what lines you're talking about. The only vertical lines I see on the image given in the question are the y-axis and the ticks on the x-axis. I don't see any gridlines. The question title clearly states horizontal line.

Comment: OK. Found the vertical gridlines. They exist in the codepen which was linked in the original version of the question. They don't exist in the codepen which was linked in the edit 6 minutes after the original version of the question.

Comment: @Makyen Yea I know, it's kinda confusing *(so as the case for OP)*. Horizontal gridlines actually belongs to y-axis and Vertical to x-axis.

Comment: What they're associated with I understand. I just didn't know why you were talking about them when they were in neither the image in the question, nor the codepen I had looked at. It wasn't until I brought up the [question revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46261082/revisions) and then went to the codepen linked in the original version of the question that I realized the vertical gridlines existed in the original codepen.