# Adding a total to the top of a stacked bar chart in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image]

As you can see in the image i've been asked with added some totals to the top of a stacked bar chart. I cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish this though. My graph so far looks like it needs to but without the totals at the top.

Here's what I have.
[image]
any help would be appreciated.

```
const dailySalesConfig = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: dailySalesData,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                color: 'white',
                formatter: function(value, context) {
                    return `$${value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")}M`;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom' 
            }
        },
        responsive: false,
        scales: {
            x: {
                stacked: true,
                grid: {
                    display: false
                }
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {
                    display:false
                },
                grid: {
                    display:false
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Here are my options for the chart.

[JS Fiddle link to demo/example](https://jsfiddle.net/camerontbelt/uxfgtybq/)

Comment: Can you please add your code? It's hard to say how to help without seeing it.

Comment: @JakeL code has been added.

Comment: @DarthScitus, it would really help if you can replicate it on https://jsfiddle.net/ so that it will be easy to experiment around the code. You can provide a minimal example there. Just by looking at the code it would be difficult to surmise the answer

Comment: @mandy8055 ive added a jsfiddle link to the question.

Comment: Is THIS a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50601605/125981 or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/46260551/125981

Comment: Probably at least 6 more examples of this in questions/answers on here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss can you link one?

Comment: I linked two, search for more... search engine returns 3400+ results with this: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chart.js%22+add+column+total+above+bar+stack+site%3Astackoverflow.com&sca_esv=576575424&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS1078US1079&biw=1920&bih=931&ei=0GY5ZYOsCtHe5NoP9uG16Aw&ved=0ahUKEwiD1LeI8pGCAxVRL1kFHfZwDc0Q4dUDCBA&oq=%22chart.js%22+add+column+total+above+bar+stack+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiQiJjaGFydC5qcyIgYWRkIGNvbHVtbiB0b3RhbCBhYm92ZSBiYXIgc3RhY2sgc2l0ZTpzdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmNvbUi25QFQgLIBWKnUAXACeACQAQCYAVKgAc0BqgEBM7gBDMgBAPgBAeIDBBgBIEGIBgE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

Answer (score 1):

You just need to play around with `formatter` function to achieve your purpose. I have created a `totalizer` plugin and used it inside `formatter` to calulate and display the total. Also, note I have addded some padding to make the data visible. You can adjust them as per your need:

```js
const dailySalesConfig = {
   type: 'bar',
   data: dailySalesData,
   options: {
   layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 50,
            right: 50,
            top: 50,
            bottom: 50
        }
    },
       plugins: {
           datalabels: {
               color: 'black',
               display: true,
               anchor: 'end',
               align: 'top',
               formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                  const total = ctx.chart.$totalizer.totals[ctx.dataIndex]
                  return `${total.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                    style: 'currency',
                    currency: 'USD'
                  })}`
               },
               display: function(ctx) {
                  return ctx.datasetIndex === ctx.chart.$totalizer.utmost
               }
           },
//rest of code...
```

The plugin would look like:

```js
const totalizer = {
 id: 'totalizer',
 beforeUpdate: chart => {
   let totals = {}
   let utmost = 0
   chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, datasetIndex) => {
     if (chart.isDatasetVisible(datasetIndex)) {
       utmost = datasetIndex
       dataset.data.forEach((value, index) => {
         totals[index] = (totals[index] || 0) + value
       })
     }
   })
   chart.$totalizer = {
     totals: totals,
     utmost: utmost
   }
 }
}
```

***[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2bjoy8ad/)***

Comment: the only issue I see with this is the missing numbers in the middle of each stacked bar. So they want it to look like the example with the individual numbers then the total on top. Does the formatter allow for two sets like that?

Comment: @DarthScitus that should be pretty easy ryt? Just use an array of `data-labels`.

Comment: i have no idea how easy it is, thats why im asking the question. I literally have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get any solution to work, so I just added a table with no styling and positioned it absolutely on the page to mimic the data being on top of each bar. Not what I wanted but it works.

EDIT:
While the above works fine, I was able to get the formatter set up to properly format the data. It requires an extra dataset where you set the data to 0 and the background color to rgb that is fully transparent.
Once you have that extra data set added, you can use the formatter to add your data.

```
formatter: function(value, index, array) {
    //console.log(index);
    if (index.datasetIndex < 4) {
        const percent = Math.round(value * 100 / totals[index.dataIndex]);
        return `${percent}%`;
    } else {
        const a = (totals[index.dataIndex] / 1000000).toFixed(2);
        console.log(a);
        return `$${a}M`;
    }
},
```

Example dataset:

```
, {
     label: '',
     backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132, 0)',
     data: ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
     stack: 'Stack 0'
   }
```