# gradient bar charts with react & chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I want to have a horizontal bar chart with react and chart.js and react-chartjs-2 this chart should be divided in tow part **yellow and red** when the data is change for example.[like this image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260551/stacked-horizontal-bar-chart-along-total-count-with-chart-js)
but the issue is that it show all charts in red.

You can see my complete code - this my `bar-Chart` componen :

```
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
   import Chart from "chart.js/auto";
   import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

   import "./BarChart.css";

   const BarChart = (props) => {
       const [Chartdata, setData] = useState(null);

       useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props);

        setData({
         labels: props.labels,
        datasets: [
           {
           label: props.globalLabel,
           data: props.data,
           backgroundColor: (context) => {
           const { ctx, chartArea, scales } = context.chart;
           if (!chartArea || !props.colorData) return null;
           const { top, bottom, left, right } = chartArea;
            const { x, y } = scales;
            let gradients = [];
            const colorDataLength = props.colorData.length;
            if (colorDataLength !== props.data.length) return null;
            for (let i = 0; i < colorDataLength; i++) {
              const gradientSegment = ctx.createLinearGradient(
               0,
               left,
               0,
               right
              );
              gradientSegment.addColorStop(0, props.colorData[i][0].color);

              for (let j = 1; j < props.colorData[i].length - 1; j++) {
            // props.colorData[i][j].point
            //props.colorData[i][j].color
  
               let border =
                 (right - x.getPixelForValue(props.colorData[i][j].point)) /
                 (right - left);
                 console.log(border);
                 if (border > 1) border = 1;
                   gradientSegment.addColorStop(
                      border,
                    props.colorData[i][j - 1].color
                    );
                    gradientSegment.addColorStop(
                     border,
                     props.colorData[i][j].color
                   );
                   }

                 gradientSegment.addColorStop(
                 1,
                props.colorData[i][props.colorData[i].length - 1].color
               );
             gradients.push(gradientSegment);
            }

            return gradients;
            },
             borderColor: props.borderColor || "rgb(100,150,150)",
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
           ],
          });
          }, [props]);

  return (
    <div className={`${props.className} bar--height`}>
     {!!Chartdata && (
       <Bar
          options={{
             indexAxis: "y", // Rotate the chart horizontally
             maintainAspectRatio: false,
              responsive: true,
             scales: {
               x: {
                 beginAtZero: true,
              },
              y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
             },
            },
         }}
           data={Chartdata}
        />
       )}
    </div>
  );
  };

  export default React.memo(BarChart);
```

in main comp:

```
   <BarChart
      data={Array(7).fill(10)}
      labels={DUUMYY_LABLES}
      colorData={colorData}
      className="AnalyticCharts--charts--div"
    />
```

color data looks like this:

```
[
[
    {
        "point": 0,
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "point": 10,
        "color": "red"
    }
],
[
    {
        "point": 0,
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "point": 5,
        "color": "yellow"
    },
    {
        "point": 7,
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "point": 10,
        "color": "red"
    }
],
[
    {
        "point": 0,
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "point": 10,
        "color": "red"
    }
],
[
    {
        "point": 0,
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "point": 10,
        "color": "red"
    }
],
[
    {
        "point": 0,
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "point": 10,
        "color": "red"
    }
],
[
    {
        "point": 0,
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "point": 10,
        "color": "red"
    }
],
[
    {
        "point": 0,
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "point": 10,
        "color": "red"
    }
]]
```

I want to see my second bar in red color from  0 to 5 and then in yellow from 5 to 7 and again red from 7 to 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for chart to behave correctly, I should change these lines and it will be fine:

```
            const gradientSegment =  
             ctx.createLinearGradient(right,0,left,0);

           let border =
              (left - x.getPixelForValue(props.colorData[i][j].point)) /
              (left - right);
```